# Ember toggle element in an array

Tags: ember.js

What is the Ember way to do the following?

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    change: function(){
      var model = this.get('model');
      model[0] = true;
      this.set('model', model);
    }
  }
});
```

I want to toggle an element (index 0 in this example) in model.

Here is the jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/doyejipagu/1/edit. The change to the model is not being reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `replace` to modify the array:

```
change: function(){
  this.get('model').replace(0, 1, [true]);
}
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_replace. The above means "starting at position 0, replace 1 element, with the single element `true`". `replace` notifies Ember that the array contents have changed, so it is reflected everywhere.

It would be nice if there were a `replaceAt` API, allowing us to just say `model.replaceAt(0, true)`, but there's not. Of course, you could write your own:

```
Ember.MutableArray.reopen({
  replaceAt: function(pos, val) {
    return this.replace(pos, 1, [val]);
  }
});
```

The problem with your code is that nothing alerts Ember to the fact that the internal values of model have changed. `model[0] = true` triggers nothing. Your `this.set('model', model)` does not change the value of the `model` property itself; so neither does it trigger any observers or bindings.

You could also create a new array (here using `slice`), which would work:

```
var model = this.get('model').slice();
model[0] = true;
this.set('model', model);
```

Now, Ember sees that `model` has changed, and does all its magic.

Answer (score -2):

What you try to do is not possible. A model either has to be an object or an array of objects otherwise you cannot set properties on it.

So you could do for example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
         return [
             Ember.Object.create({value: false}),
             Ember.Object.create({value: true}),
             Ember.Object.create({value: false})
         ];
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        change: function(){
            this.get('model')[0].toggleProperty('value');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. A model can be anything. It's just a property with a value. There is no reason a model cannot be a plain old array with single values. In fact, the default Ember hello world app uses a model of `['red', 'blue', 'yellow']`.

Comment: You are right, my formulation was a little bit rubbish, what I meant was that ember cannot observe any change like you mentioned in your solution.